# Android ListView,show a message if arrayList of arrayAdapter is empty

Tags: android

I need help.
I have a Listview.setListAdapter(arrayAdapter) and array adapter have a arrayList.

If my arrayList is empty it shows loading images, it is normal, but how can i show a message if my arrayList is empty?
 Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: If you can show an image then why cannot you show a message ?

Comment: check arraList.size()

Comment: just replace or add toast code with loading code

Comment: my listview is a fragment and this image is default, so i have to create another fragment if  arraList.size()<1, but i dont want to create another fragment. My question is how to replace this image to another image or a text view without creating another fragment?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The common way is setting an empty textview (@android:id/empty) after the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</ListView>

<TextView 
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/empty_list" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then set set the empty view to the listview:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
TextView emptyText = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
lv.setEmptyView(emptyText);
```

This should show items in the list whenever they are, and show the textview when not.

Answer (score 0):

With a Toast.

```
if(list == null || list.size() == 0)
    Toast.makeText(context, "The list is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: A Toast is not ideal.you want the user to always see a message telling them there is nothing to display at the moment.